# Base 64 PDF Data URL In iFrame not displaying on mobile

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, mobile

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,<BINARY_DATA_HERE>"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to get a PDF in a data URI to show in an iFrame.  It works great on desktop, but just shows blank on mobile and even in chrome developer tools in device view it shows up blank as well.  Any ideas on why this is happening or how to fix it? Thank you!

Example: http://seemly-fuel.surge.sh/

For context:

desktop:
[image]

mobile: 
[image]

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution for this.